# Inserting a python variable into a query

Tags: python, mysql, variables

I'm trying to pull back a fairly involved query from mysql - I've got the connection working OK, and can successfully complete the query when I hard code the values.

I'd like to make one of the values a python variable - I am following the method I found here: [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python) as the listed usecase seems pretty much the same as mine.

The mysql execute function I am using is different to the solved problem, and I can't figure out where to place the python variable into the execute call.

My code:

```
targetPUID = "fmt/123"

cur.execute("""
(
SELECT `PUID`,`DROID_V`,`SIG_V`,`SPEED`,
COUNT(distinct IF(sourcelist.hasExtension=1,NAME,NULL)) as Ext,
COUNT(distinct IF(sourcelist.hasExtension=0,NAME,NULL)) as NoExt,
COUNT(distinct NAME) as `All`
FROM sourcelist, main_small
WHERE sourcelist.SourcePUID ="%s" AND main_small.NAME = sourcelist.SourceFileName
GROUP BY `PUID`,`DROID_V`,`SIG_V`,`SPEED` ORDER BY `DROID_V` ASC, `SIG_V`
 )
""")
```

I know I need to place a reference to my variable `targetPUID`to link up with the `%s` in the query.

___________________FIXED___________________

OK, got it working:

```
 cur.execute("""
 (
 SELECT `PUID`,`DROID_V`,`SIG_V`,`SPEED`,
 COUNT(distinct IF(sourcelist.hasExtension=1,NAME,NULL)) as Ext,
 COUNT(distinct IF(sourcelist.hasExtension=0,NAME,NULL)) as NoExt,
 COUNT(distinct NAME) as `All`
 FROM sourcelist, main_small
 WHERE sourcelist.SourcePUID =%s AND main_small.NAME = sourcelist.SourceFileName
 GROUP BY `PUID`,`DROID_V`,`SIG_V`,`SPEED` ORDER BY `DROID_V` ASC, `SIG_V`
 )
""",targetPUID)
```

and

```
 targetPUID = "x-fmt/409"
```

I don't have enough rep to add the fix yet. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
cur.execute("""
(
SELECT `PUID`,`DROID_V`,`SIG_V`,`SPEED`,
COUNT(distinct IF(sourcelist.hasExtension=1,NAME,NULL)) as Ext,
COUNT(distinct IF(sourcelist.hasExtension=0,NAME,NULL)) as NoExt,
COUNT(distinct NAME) as `All`
FROM sourcelist, main_small
WHERE sourcelist.SourcePUID = %s AND main_small.NAME = sourcelist.SourceFileName
GROUP BY `PUID`,`DROID_V`,`SIG_V`,`SPEED` ORDER BY `DROID_V` ASC, `SIG_V`
 )
""",(int(targetPUID),))
```

Comment: I did try that, and it returns an empty list - `()` thanks though.

Comment: Try replacing `%s` with the `targetPUID` value in the query and manually execute it with a SQL application to see if the query works.

Comment: Yupe, it works fine when manually implemented via this python method, so I know its the variable aspect thats at fault.

Comment: If `targetPUID` is an integer, try converting the variable to an integer when passing it to the execute function or try my revised code again.

Answer (score 1):

```
cur.execute(..., (targetPUID,))
```

Comment: I gave that a go, I just and an empty list back `()` if I substitute the `%s` for the sting inside the variable I get full list as expected. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

OK, got it working:

```
 cur.execute("""
 (
 SELECT `PUID`,`DROID_V`,`SIG_V`,`SPEED`,
 COUNT(distinct IF(sourcelist.hasExtension=1,NAME,NULL)) as Ext,
 COUNT(distinct IF(sourcelist.hasExtension=0,NAME,NULL)) as NoExt,
 COUNT(distinct NAME) as `All`
 FROM sourcelist, main_small
 WHERE sourcelist.SourcePUID =%s AND main_small.NAME = sourcelist.SourceFileName
 GROUP BY `PUID`,`DROID_V`,`SIG_V`,`SPEED` ORDER BY `DROID_V` ASC, `SIG_V`
 )
""",targetPUID)
```

and

```
targetPUID = "x-fmt/409"
```

Comment: @Secator I will do as soon as I am allowed (another 23 hours - sorry) - I don't have enough rep yet.